# Unity Object moves when AddForceAtPosition is applied when it should only rotate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I have a game object in unity I'd like to thrust vector around with some forces. At the moment I'm trying to add some realistic rotation forces hence using AddForceAtPosition using an offset from the rigidbody center of mass. Yet when i run the game, the object starts moving slightly in addition to the rotation. No other forces are present and there is no drag.

```
rb.AddForceAtPosition(transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up * 5), transform.position + transform.TransformDirection(mainThrustPt));
```

Comment: [Watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWVZ6APXM4w)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition` function apply both *torque* and *force* on the object. this means that the Object will be rotated and moved at the-same time.

If you just want to apply a rotational force that doesn't move the Object, use the `Rigidbody.AddTorque` or `Rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque` which will only apply a rotational force to the Object.

You can also free the Rigidbody x,y,z position if you don't want it to move but the movement behavior of the object will be weird sometimes when this is done.

[image]

> Yet when i run the game, the object starts moving slightly in addition
>   to the rotation.

If the Object is moving without adding force to it or without using `AddForceAtPosition`, then gravity is pulling it. Disable "Use Gravity" as I did in the image above.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But it doesn't quite fix my problem. I have disabled gravity from the start. Imagine a spaceship sitting out in zero gravity with a thruster sitting on the wing. If I fire that thruster downwards, I would expect the spaceship to start rolling without moving anywhere.

Comment: If you disable gravity and run the game, the object will not and should not move unless you are adding force to it from another script or moving it's transform. Disable all your scrips and enable them one by one until you find which script is adding force or moving it.

Comment: I have a single script with a single force and the problem persists.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have one or two scripts. As long as you are adding force to it it will move. If you don't add force to it, it won't move as long as gravity is disabled and no other object is pushing it. Do not add a single force and it won't move. See where I talked about torque for only rotational force

Comment: Ahh finally I get it now! I had  fundamental misunderstanding of the physics involved and now reading your comments makes perfect sense! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use AddTorque if you need rotation.

Answer (score 0):

If you pushed the edge of a ball tied up with string, you would expect it to swing as well as spin. Try using this before applying the force:

```
rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationY | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationZ;
```